# Empty String to Double C#

Tags: c#, double

At this moment i am trying to get a double value from textbox like this:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) ? 0.0 : Double.Parse(textBox1.Text)
```

But there is a problem, i cant get how to parse empty textbox?

For example if to try this code with OleDb and Excel with empty textbox, we will get error

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What values do you put in the text box to get it to throw that exception? You should take a look at the `Double.TryParse` method, too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx

Comment: Did you set the culture right? Doubles are represented differently in different cultures. Dutch for example uses "0,0" instead of "0.0".

Comment: MrFox, yes you noticed right, i had a problem with this too, but atm its ok.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
double val;
if(!double.TryParse(textBox.Text,out val))
    val = 0.0
```

Comment: No need for the `if` statement if all you're going to do is set val to 0.

Comment: Ive modified your code to
**double value = Double.TryParse(resultBox.Text, out value) ? value : 0.0;**
and this works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Did you try [`Double.TryParse(String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Double%)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx)?

This could help to solve problems with various number formats.

Answer (score 1):

```
double result;
Double.TryParse("",out result);
```

If TryParse is true, the result will have a double value
Further you can use if condition,

```
result = Double.TryParse("",out result) ? result : 0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Double.TryParse` is unable to parse the string, it returns false and sets the out parameter to 0.

```
double d;
if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d)
{
  // valid number
}
else
{
  // not a valid number and d = 0;
}
```

Or

```
double d;
double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d)
// do something with d.
```

Also note that you can use the out parameter in additional logic within the same if statement:

```
double d;
if(double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out d) && d > 500 && d < 1000)
{
  // valid number and the number is between 501 and 9999
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use Double.TryParse that doesn't throw exception?